# Why does Spring autowire Map into another wrapped Map?

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, dependency-injection

I have the following bean definition

```
@Bean(name="producerConfig")
public Map<String, Object> producerConfig() {
```

and the following injection declaration

```
@Service
@Component("...)
public class DataAssetSnapshotPublisherLive {
    public SnapshotPublisherLive(..., @Qualifier("producerConfig") Map<String, Object> producerConfig) {
        ...
    }
```

I would expect, that `producerPublisher` will be injected into `producerPublisher` variable, because it has the same type and qualifier.

Instead of this I see in debugger that it is wrapped

```
producerConfig = {LinkedHashMap@12556}  size = 1
 "producerConfig" -> {HashMap@12561}  size = 27
  key = "producerConfig"
  value = {HashMap@12561}  size = 27
```

I.e. `producerConfig` is initialized with new `HashMap` and one element is added to the hash map.

Why and how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of intervention of "Spring magic" in unexpected ways.

In this case, the **map autowiring** works: if you inject a `Map<String, SomeClass>` then Spring considers it as a special case. that you want to inject all registered beans that override SomeClass.

> Autowiring Arrays, Collections, and Maps
> In case of an array, Collection, or Map dependency type, the container autowires all beans matching the declared value type. For such purposes, the map keys must be declared as type String which will be resolved to the corresponding bean names. Such a container-provided collection will be ordered, taking into account Ordered and @Order values of the target components, otherwise following their registration order in the container. Alternatively, a single matching target bean may also be a generally typed Collection or Map itself, getting injected as such.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html

So essentially what you are getting in your debugger (i.e., LinkedHashMap) is the list of all beans that:

- implement the type specified in map declaration (in this case Object, a lot of stuff implements that)
- match qualifier "producerConfig" (in this case, there is onlye a single matching bean so only 1 entry in LinkedHashMap).

These beans are accompanied by bean names and sorted by registration order, hence LinkedHashMap.

Note that it does not happen if the key type of your map is not String. If you replace `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<Integer, Object>` the behavior will be totally different and you will get only single bean injected as you would expect initially.

Regarding "how to prevent this": I am not sure if this behavior can be switched off, the documentation does not say anything about it. I think the most reasonable solution is to create a wrapper class and inject it instead of a injecting a Map directly.